# UserPasswordCredential .Net Standard

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, .net-standard

I want to call graph api,  https://graph.windows.net for that I am using a delegated permission as below for token

```
UserPasswordCredential credentials = new UserPasswordCredential("username", "password");
AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(string.Format("https://login.windows.net/{0}", "mytenant.onmicrosoft.com"));
var accessToken = authContext.AcquireTokenAsync("https://graph.windows.net", clientId, credentials).Result.AccessToken;
```

I am not a tenant admin and in AAD and I cannot add specific Applications as an owner for app authentication. This was working in full .net is there a workaround for this in .net standard? As I cannot use app authentication in this scenario.

I am trying to convert and webjob to an Azure function.

Comment: What are using the token for ? you can use `Managed Identity` so you don't have to specify the credentials: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2018/06/13/using-managed-service-identity-msi-with-and-azure-app-service-or-an-azure-function/

Answer (score 2):

> is there a workaround for this in .net standard?

Yes, we could use the rest API to get the token directly.

```
Post  https://login.windows.net/<tenant-id>/oauth2/token
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
grant_type=password
&resource={resource}
&username={username}
&password={password}
&client_id={client-id}
```

The following is the demo code to get access token

```
var tenantId = "xxx.onmicrosoft.com";
var userName = "xxx@xxxx.onmicrosoft.com";
var password = "xxxxxx";
var clientId = "xxxxxxx";
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var tokenEndpoint = $"https://login.windows.net/{tenantId}/oauth2/token";
                var accept = "application/json";

                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", accept);
                string postBody = $"resource=https://graph.windows.net/&client_id={clientId}&grant_type=password&username={userName}&password={password}";
                using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(tokenEndpoint, new StringContent(postBody, Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")))
                {
                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        var jsonresult = JObject.Parse(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
                        var  token = (string)jsonresult["access_token"];
                    }
                }
            }
```

**Note:** Azure AD **native** application is requried.